# Google Apps Script: Get specific data and preview elsewhere

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet of a long (sorted) list, with column A with date and column B with time and then some data on columns c,d,e,f.

I want to have a script function that compares current date-time to the date and time from columns A & B and then copies to columns i,j,k,l,m,n on rows 1-4 the "upcoming" data.

So I'm thinking of something like this, but unsure how to finish it. Any ideas?

```
function myFunction()
{
  var d = new Date();
  var now = d.getTime();
  var as = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = as.getDataRange().getValues(); //this seems to be wrong, because I don't need all DataRange, only first 6 columns, but as many rows as those having data
  var c = 0;
  for(i in data)
  {
    var row = data[i];
    //var rowdate = ??;
    if (now < rowdate)
    {
      c++;
      //copy from row to destination location
    }
    if (c > 4) break;
  }
}
```

Comment: have you had any progress on this or you are still stuck? can you share your sheet somehow so that I can see it maybe?

Comment: To get your data, you can use [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(Integer,Integer,Integer,Integer)) instead of getDataRange(). Then, you can get like "var data = as.getRange(1, 1, as.[getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow), 6).getValues()", which will give you only the 6 columns you're looking for.

Comment: Here's a link to view a sample file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jzr06Fh0Yo3f460BOi6itCOG8wBk6-calhnPztkJ2sU/edit?usp=sharing